# (Linear Regression) Proving that Linear Regression is linear invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-regression

I want to ask how to show that Linear Regression is linear invariant? The problem is specified in the following picture:
[image]

Here is the "solution" for the problem. But I really get confused by its second step: Why $(Z^TZ)^{-1} = Z^{-1}Z^{-T}$?  The matrix Z is not a square matrix. I am wondering how this is legit? I will also greatly appreciate if anyone can give alternative solution to this problem. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Have a read of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices Turns out $A^TA$ has this funny property.

Comment: amd: Can you explain why what you said holds for Z being a rectangular matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: distributing the inverse as they did only works if $Z$ is square, which it is usually not.

A valid solution is as follows:
\begin{align}
\theta' &= (Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^Ty
\\ &= ((XA^T)^T(XA^T))^{-1}(XA^T)^Ty
\\ & = (AX^TXA^T)^{-1}AX^Ty
\\ & = [A^{-T}(X^TX)^{-1}A^{-1}]AX^Ty
\\ &= A^{-T}(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty 
\\ &= A^{-T}\theta
\end{align}
The trick here is not to break up the product $X^TX$ when distributing the inverse.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your solution works perfectly! I also wonder if it is possible to say $(Z^TZ)^{-1}=Z^{-1}Z^{-T}$ if we consider the inverse as the generalized inverse? I am thinking if the suggested solution is in fact also valid, but only that they used the definition of "inverse" differently than I thought

Comment: Well with the usual [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition) for this context, we actually have $Z^{\dagger} = (Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T$ (when $Z$ has full column rank).  However, I do not suspect that this is what they had in mind.